# Aloe leaf has discoloration

Tags: aloe

I am new to caring for Aloe. I have a plant with a leaf that has brown discoloration. The leaf has started to curl around the spot, almost like it is damaged.

Does anyone know what the likely cause of this is? Do you think I should remove the leaf from the plant?

[image: aloe with discoloration]

[image: aloe with discoloration]

Comment: It looks like it was pinched in that one spot.  It's not going to become healthy again, so I'd be inclined to pluck it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a pair of scissors and cut below that blackened necrotic patch, at a sharp angle, remove the leaf.

Normal stuff that happens no matter what.  If this happens again we need to look at causes. Your plant looks very healthy other than this one leaf.

Comment: Thanks Stormy. Do I have to worry about cutting it and leaving the gel exposed? Is there any way to make it "heal" faster after I cut it. I heard from someone that it can cause it to rot in the soil if there's any exposed gel.

Comment: Don't worry about the gel.  The plant takes care of its own injuries.  It would not cause rot.  Just cut at a sharp angle, not straight across.  Don't cut it  completely off, leave an inch or two sticking out of the soil. Go scrape your knee or something  and test your gel!  grins!  Have you ever used this gel to see what happens?  I found that the older plants with at least 2" wide leaves have the best, stinkiest gel.  Put it on an open owwie and it turns it black like a scab.  In half an hour.  My mom sent me aloe vera to take, in a drink...UGH!